# Can anyone explain how this sentence makes sense?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Note that it is possible for "*p* only if *q*" to be true at the same time that "*p* if *q*" is false. For instance, to say that John will break the world's record only if he runs the mile in under four minutes does not mean that John will break the world's record if he runs the mile in under four minutes. His time could be under four minutes but still not be fast enough to break the record.

original [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00pzA.png)

If you say John will break the world's record ONLY if he runs the mile in under four minutes and John then does run under four minutes does it literally not mean that he broke it because we just said he'll break it only if he does that? Can anyone explain this